# OSX extended attributes and NFS

Tags: macos, nfs, hfs, hfs+

I have multiple users working on a fileserver, mainly using Photoshop, InDesign and alikes. Samba (3.5.6) does not seem responsive enough (using 'socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_KEEPALIVE IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536').

Hardware, disk i/o, network etc all ruled out.

After some initial testing, we decided to switch to NFS. It did however not take long before files and directories started to become read-only to the users (but of course not to me, not using MacOS X's "Finder"). After some digging I found the HFS+ extended attributes to be the likely cause. After removing them most problems have been solved, but not all. The problem is that this will happen again as soon as I let the users use NFS again.

NFS server options: rw,async,insecure,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001
NFS client options: basically none, tested "noacl" and some other options with no luck.

Should I find a way to configure the clients not to use extended attributes, or can NFS be configured in a way that the clients cant use them?
How is this typically solved?

Comment: What about using Adobe Bridge? It does not count towards a license with your Adobe products, meaning you can install it on any computer and access it that way, independent of the OS

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. I must say that it doesn't seem more portable than NFS, and more specifically I cannot imagine that such a product is faster than a well configured NFS share. It actually seems to be a graphical interface for editing, displaying and such - which would then have to reside on a NFS partition.